# rebuilding a meeting schedules

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am attempting recreate how many meetings were scheduled for a particular day by each day leading up to that day

for example:
How many meetings happened on 2022-05-17
How many meetings were scheduled to happened on 2022-05-17 the day before
How many meetings were scheduled to  happened on 2022-05-17 the two days before
How many meetings were scheduled to  happened on 2022-05-17 the three days before etc

I have a working solution, but I have decades of data to sort through, and it takes roughly 16 hours per site to run.  
I am hoping there is a clever dplyr or data.table solution that will speed this up considerably.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
scheduledate <- as.Date(c('2022-06-05','2022-06-05','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06',
                          '2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06',
                          '2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06',
                          '2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06',
                          '2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06',
                          '2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06',
                          '2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06',
                          '2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06','2022-06-06')
                        , format="%Y-%m-%d")

record_create_date <- as.Date(c('2022-06-05','2022-05-20','2022-05-25','2022-05-02','2022-05-25',
                                '2022-04-14','2022-04-15','2022-04-26','2022-05-25',
                                '2022-05-17','2022-05-24','2022-05-20','2022-05-04','2022-06-01',
                                '2022-06-05','2022-06-06','2022-03-03','2022-04-26','2022-05-27',
                                '2022-03-31','2022-05-04','2022-04-12','2022-04-11','2022-04-08',
                                '2022-03-22','2022-04-20','2022-04-12','2022-04-27','2022-04-22',
                                '2022-04-25','2022-03-31','2022-04-20','2022-06-06','2022-03-30',
                                '2022-03-28','2022-05-06','2022-01-25','2022-04-25','2022-04-25')
                              , format="%Y-%m-%d")

cancel_date <- as.Date(c('2022-06-05','2022-06-02',NA,NA,NA,'2022-06-06',
                         NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                         NA,'2022-06-06',NA,NA,NA,
                         '2022-05-24','2022-05-19',NA,NA,NA,
                         NA,NA,NA,'2022-06-06','2022-06-01',
                                    '2022-06-03','2022-05-18','2022-05-10','2022-06-06','2022-06-02',
                                    '2022-06-06','2022-05-09','2022-06-06','2022-05-31','2022-06-06')
                                    , format="%Y-%m-%d")
                     
had_meeting <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,
                           1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
                     
combined_DF <- data.frame(scheduledate, record_create_date, cancel_date, had_meeting)
```

this is my current solution:

```
scheduled_DF <- combined_DF %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(scheduledate)) %>%
  complete(Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by="day")) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(meetings_conducted = sum(had_meeting)) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  as_tbl_time(index = Date)

curtime <- Sys.time()
final_df <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(scheduled_DF)) {
  pred_date <- scheduled_DF[i,]$Date
  
  tmp_df <- NULL
  tmp_df <- scheduled_DF[i,]
  
  # looking backwards 30 days
  for (j in 1:30) {
    
    # subset off the data set we need
    # 
    tmp <- combined_DF[(combined_DF$scheduledate == pred_date
                    & combined_DF$record_create_date <= (pred_date - j)
                    & (combined_DF$cancel_date > (pred_date - j) | is.na(combined_DF$cancel_date))
    )
    ,]
    
    tmp_df <- tmp_df %>% add_column(tmp_col = nrow(tmp))
    names(tmp_df)[names(tmp_df) == "tmp_col"] <- paste0("scheduled_days_out_", j)
  }
  
  if (!exists('final_df')) {
    final_df <- tmp_df
  } else {
    final_df <- rbind(final_df, tmp_df)
  }
}
paste("loop took ", difftime(Sys.time(), curtime, units = "min"), " minutes")
```

the final df should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the final_DF sample, it looks like a truth condition for each day's lag.  I'm sure you could tweak the summarise statements to a function and dynamically generate columns.  I just filled thirty days' worth of columns here.

The runtime on the trivial sample is about the same (within 0.0003 seconds) and gets the output dataframe.

```
method_2 <- function(combined_DF){
grouped <- combined_DF %>%
    mutate(Date = as.Date(scheduledate)) %>%
    complete(Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by="day")) %>%
    mutate(scheduled_days_out = as.numeric(difftime(scheduledate, record_create_date, units="days"))) %>%
    mutate(cancelled_days_out = as.numeric(difftime(scheduledate, cancel_date, units="days"))) %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise(meetings_conducted = sum(had_meeting),
              col_1 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 1) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 1))),
              col_2 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 2) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 2))),
              col_3 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 3) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 3))),
              col_4 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 4) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 4))),
              col_5 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 5) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 5))),
              col_6 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 6) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 6))),
              col_7 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 7) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 7))),
              col_8 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 8) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 8))),
              col_9 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 9) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 9))),
              col_10 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 10) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 10))),
              col_11 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 11) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 11))),
              col_12 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 12) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 12))),
              col_13 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 13) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 13))),
              col_14 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 14) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 14))),
              col_15 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 15) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 15))),
              col_16 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 16) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 16))),
              col_17 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 17) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 17))),
              col_18 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 18) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 18))),
              col_19 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 19) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 19))),
              col_20 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 20) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 20))),
              col_21 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 21) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 21))),
              col_22 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 22) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 22))),
              col_23 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 23) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 23))),
              col_24 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 24) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 24))),
              col_25 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 25) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 25))),
              col_26 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 26) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 26))),
              col_27 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 27) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 27))),
              col_28 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 28) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 28))),
              col_29 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 29) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 29))),
              col_30 = (sum((scheduled_days_out >= 30) & (is.na(cancelled_days_out) | (cancelled_days_out) < 30))))
return(grouped)
}

curtime <- Sys.time()
method_2_df <- method_2(combined_DF)
paste("loop took ", difftime(Sys.time(), curtime, units = "min"), " minutes")

#[1] "loop took  0.00336113770802816  minutes"
#> method_2_df

# A tibble: 2 × 32
#  Date       meetings_co…¹ col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6 col_7 col_8 col_9 col_10 col_11
#  <date>             <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#1 2022-06-05             0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1      1      1
#2 2022-06-06            21    26    25    25    26    27    27    28    28    28     28     27
```

Comment: I think that this will work, but I need some more time to verify it

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the function `lag()`. Something like this should work:

```
combined_DF |> 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(scheduledate)) |> 
  complete(Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by="day"),fill = list(had_meeting = 0)) |> 
  group_by(Date) |> 
  summarize(meetings_conducted = sum(had_meeting)) |> 
  arrange(Date) |> 
  mutate(scheduled_days_out_1 = lag(meetings_conducted,1),
         scheduled_days_out_2 = lag(meetings_conducted,2), ...)
```

You could put the mutate statements in a loop if you wanted less code

Comment: this solution does not appear to backfill what was scheduled x days out.  The combined_DF has the dates that appointments were scheduled, and the date that they were cancelled (if they were in fact cancelled).  It is the combination of these dates that are used to determine how many meetings are scheduled for a certain date, x days out.